# Boxes inline-block not aligned

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put two boxes (div) side to side, and I noticed they get misaligned when one contains text and the other is empty (in my case it contains )

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <div id="tab2">1</div>
            <div id="tab3"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```css
#tab2, #tab3 {
    width: 460px;
    min-height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: #BCC6CC 2px solid;
}
```

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbNBqL?editors=110)

Comment: Add `vertical-align: top` to fix the alignment issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello please use `vertical-align: top;` to make them align vertically in one line

```css
#tab2, #tab3 {
   width:460px; 
   min-height:300px; 
   display:inline-block; 
   border:#BCC6CC 2px solid;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/SzymonDziewonski/pen/vLKYxB)

Answer (score 0):

**Agree with @Szymon Dziewoński and also you can use this**

```
#tab2, #tab3 {
   width:460px; 
   min-height:300px; 
   display:inline-block; 
   border:#BCC6CC 2px solid;
   float: left;
   margin-left: 5px;
}
```